# how can i add an additonal output to ffmpeg to also pull out a frame for an image after segmenting

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, video-streaming, video-editing

this is my command. i need to add something to the end to pull out a vframe every second or specified seconds and save to file. i've see how to do that on its own but not as a second output. i keep trying things but just cant get it. does anyone know?

`ffmpeg -y -nostdin -hide_banner -loglevel warning -err_detect ignore_err -fflags +genpts -async 1 -probesize 5120000 -analyzeduration 5000000  -i source.m3u8 -vcodec copy -scodec copy -acodec copy -individual_header_trailer 0 -f segment -segment_format mpegts -segment_time 10 -segment_list_size 6 -segment_format_options mpegts_flags=+initial_discontinuity:mpegts_copyts=1 -segment_list_type m3u8 -segment_list_flags +live+delete -segment_list output_%d.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Add the 2nd output right after the first. Use the select video filter to pick the nearest frame at each X seconds interval, and setpts filter afterwards to generate a smooth timestamps. Noe that this will decode the entire video stream. It will be lest costly to run a solo command on the saved segments.

Use

`ffmpeg -y -nostdin -hide_banner -loglevel warning -err_detect ignore_err -fflags +genpts -async 1 -probesize 5120000 -analyzeduration 5000000  -i source.m3u8 -vcodec copy -scodec copy -acodec copy -individual_header_trailer 0 -f segment -segment_format mpegts -segment_time 10 -segment_list_size 6 -segment_format_options mpegts_flags=+initial_discontinuity:mpegts_copyts=1 -segment_list_type m3u8 -segment_list_flags +live+delete -segment_list output_%d.ts -vf "select='lt(mod(t\,X),0.007)',setpts=N/FR/TB" -q:v 10 frames-%d.jpg`

Comment: thanks! `-vf "select='lt(mod(t\,X),0.007)',setpts=N/FR/TB" -q:v 10 frames-%d.jpg` this is different than the solution i have for getting a the frame every second which looks like this:
`-s 120x120 -vf fps=1/1 -y -q:v 1 -update 1 image.bmp` it appears mine is actually working by just to appending it. the issue i was having i think is the php script handling the appending isn't parsing correctly. but why is your way so different? is it better? also as you see i just need one image to continuously update as a still shot preview of the stream.